# How to configure CORS annotations in Openshift (OKD) routes?

Tags: openshift, okd

How to configure CORS annotations in Openshift (OKD) routes? i didn't find such information in documentation. For example, Ingress Nginx Controller has such annotations:

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: DNT,Scope,X-CustomHeader
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '*'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-max-age: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```